# Error in mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query i am running to insert a record but i am getting an error i am not able to get what is the problem.

```sql
INSERT INTO lft(Patientid,Patientname,Testdate,Test,Range,Result)
VALUES('$Patientid','$Patientname','$Testdate','$Test','$Range','$Result')
```

The error is :

> ERROR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Range,Result)VALUES('1052','ADITYA RAJESH KHATEKE','4/3/2012','CHest','30','23')' at line 1

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RANGE` is [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) in `mysql` use `` ` `` around it

```
INSERT INTO lft(`Patientid`,`Patientname`,`Testdate`,`Test`,`Range`,`Result`)
VALUES('$Patientid','$Patientname','$Testdate','$Test','$Range','$Result')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put you query like this

```
INSERT INTO lft(`Patientid`,`Patientname`,`Testdate`,`Test`,`Range`,`Result`)VALUES('$Patientid','$Patientname','$Testdate','$Test','$Range','$Result')
```

Range is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Answer already given.